# @internal JavaScript documentation tag inside react code, is this jsdoc, closure, or something else?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, jsdoc

I noticed that React uses the `@internal` tag for documentation.  What program consumes this tag?  Is it jsdoc or something else?  Google Closure Compiler?  I can't find this tag on http://usejsdoc.org/ or in the Google Closure Compiler documentation.  What is it used for?

Here is an example -

```
/**
 * Warn for mutations.
 *
 * @internal
 * @param {object} object
 * @param {string} key
 */
function defineWarningProperty(object, key) {
```

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/classic/element/ReactElement.js

Comment: It's not used by Closure-compiler: https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/parsing/Annotation.java#L27

Answer (score 6):

The typescript compiler can use this tag to exclude stuff from the d.ts definition.

See the [--stripInternal option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#stripInternal) for more information.

Comment: A more up-to-date link that includes a warning on the use of `--stripInternal`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#stripInternal

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/272), it looks like the documentation is manual.